# Probability of Vacuum Fluctuations near Charges

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, experimental-physics

A short, simple enough question, if you know about field theory, which unfortunately I don't.

Are vacuum fluctuations more probable near a charge, for example an electron with negative charge?

I think this is one of the problems the renormalization procedure resolves, but if they are more probable, is there a clear mechanism for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Are vacuum fluctuations more probable near a charge, for example an electron with negative charge?**

I'm going to say no, because [renormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization) is more to do the virtual particles of QED rather than vacuum fluctuations. As for virtual particles, see [Matt Strassler's article](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/) and note this:

*"The best way to approach this concept, I believe, is to forget you ever saw the word 'particle' in the term. A virtual particle is not a particle at all"*.

They aren't short-lived real particles that pop into existence like spontaneous worms from mud. Instead they're "field quanta". It's like you divvy up an electron's field into chunks and say each is a virtual particle. The field is more intense closer to the electron, or a proton. Then when the electron and the proton attract one another they "exchange field" such that the hydrogen atom doesn't have much in the way of a field left. But there aren't any actual photons flying back and forth. Hydrogen atoms don't twinkle. And vacuum fluctuations aren't the same thing as virtual particles. For an analogy, if a real photon is an oceanic swell wave barrelling along at 8 knots, the virtual photons are a sloped abstract chunks of it, and vacuum fluctuations are something like the little ripplets on the surface of the sea. They're responsible for [the Casimir effect](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/casimir.html). But the force there is very weak, unlike the immensely strong [Coulomb force](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elefor.html#c2) between the electron and proton.